# Selenium test fails to start using operadriver

Tags: java, selenium, operadriver

My cross browser test fails only for opera driver since it is working with all the other drivers (chrome, firefox and ie).

Here is the java code.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.opera.driver", "...\\operadriver.exe");
driver = new OperaDriver();
```

Here is the testng class.

```
  <test name="OperaTestCases">  
      <parameter name="browser" value="opera"/>  
      <classes> 
         <class name="crossBrowser.Test"/> 
      </classes> 
  </test>
```

browser is opening but nothing is happening. and test fails. :)

Comment: what is your opera version?

Comment: Im using opera 41

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to install Opera 38 and add following code instead your java code.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "...\\operadriver.exe");
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

I  have used new ChromeDriver(). This will start Opera since we are using OperaChromiumDriver. I think this is because the new Opera is based on Chromium and OperaChromiumDriver is a WebDriver implementation derived from ChromeDriver [See https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver].

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thank u very much @quality products. I'll try this. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now my test is running. :)